# JavaScript | Не функционирует .pause()

Tags: javascript, аудио

Приветствую.

Решил сделать проигрыватель радио на сайте. В JS не силён, потому пришлось писать с нуля, используя различные источники. В конечном итоге получилось примерно следующее:

```js
function playAudio(){
  var play = document.getElementById("play");
  var pause = document.getElementById("pause");
  var audio = document.createElement('audio');
  audio.src = 'адрес_потока';

    if(pause != null){
      audio.play();

      document.getElementById("pause").remove();

      var div = document.createElement('div');
      div.className = "d5";
      div.setAttribute("id", "play");
      document.querySelector(".d1").appendChild(div);

      var div2 = document.createElement('div');
      div2.className = "d5-2";
      div2.setAttribute("id", "play");
      document.querySelector(".d1").appendChild(div2);
      }

    else if(play != null){
      audio.pause();

      document.getElementById("play").remove();
      document.getElementById("play").remove();

      var div = document.createElement('div');
      div.className = "d6";
      div.setAttribute("id", "pause");
      document.querySelector(".d1").appendChild(div);
    }
}
```

HTML-код:

```
<div class="d1" OnClick="playAudio();">
                <div class="d6" id="pause"></div>
</div>
```

Всё функционирует в полном объёме, за исключением паузы (audio.pause();). Выполняется весь код, указанный в условии, но данный фрагмент будто уходит из виду. После повторного нажатия на кнопку запускается ещё один поток "поверх" предыдущего.

---

Буду благодарен, если подскажете, где может быть ошибка.

Comment: Дайте кусок `html` кода то же.

Comment: @Igor , playAudio() вызывается при нажатии на соответствующий div. document.createElement('audio') был использован как пример с одного из аналогичного примера. Ранее использовалась конструкция: var audio = new Audio; Второй вызов удаляет второй аналогичный div, который находится в другом месте.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Когда вызывается `playAudio` и сколько раз?

Это зачем `var audio = document.createElement('audio');`?

Второй вызов `document.getElementById("play").remove();` подряд - интересно что будет делать?

Подсказываю, где может быть ошибка.

Событие `click` - всплывающее, то есть нажатие на `div`-ы `play` и `pause` будет вызывать обработку щелчка и у родителя - `div class="d1"`. Cледовательно, функция `playAudio` будет вызываться снова, создавая каждый раз новый `var audio = document.createElement('audio');`.

Comment: Понял. Ошибку увидел. Отправляюсь на доработку. Спасибо :)

Answer (score 0):

Ты проверяешь не правильно. В условии IF пропиши не  if(pause != null), а так  if (audio.paused == true) и должно все работать

Comment: Да проверка-то функционировала полноценно :) И при проверке if(pause != null) - проверяется не факт запуска потока, а состояние кнопки, которая, в свою очередь служит информатором о том запущен поток или нет. В противном случае велик шанс создания лишних div`ов, потому было принято решение проверять именно состояние кнопки, а не потока :) Однако, проблема решилась простым выносом var audio = new Audio(); за пределы функции. Спасибо за участие в решении вопроса :)